# Which site is the best for wiki of IOS, Cocoa, Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, xcode

Which site is the best for wiki documentation of iOS, Cocoa and Objective-C?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How-to articles for iPhone development, Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939/how-to-articles-for-iphone-development-objective-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I heard this book is good: Programming in Objective-C 2.0 (2nd Edition)

you can try this videos:

Programming in Objective-C 2.0 LiveLessons (Video Training):Part I: Language Fundamentals and Part II: iPhone Programming and the Foundation Framework

http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=9780321720337

Answer (score 1):

Apples developer center docs? That's where I'd look first.